# Is there any way to access variable in one function of a file to another file

Tags: python, function, import, call, python-3.5

I have 2 files prgm.py and test.py

1.prgm.py

```
def move(self)
    H=newtest.myfunction()
    i= H.index(z)
    user=newuser.my_function() 
    print(user[i])
```

How will i get user[i] in the other code named test.py

Comment: you code is not clear but basically you should import prgm and call prgm.your_val or prgm.your_fun()

Answer (score 0):

Use an **import** statement in the other file;

Like this - `from prgm import move`
Note: For this to work both of the files needs to be in the same folder or the path to the file you are importing needs to be in your PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the result, you can simply return it. In the second file, you just import the function from this source file and call it.

Given the situation, `move` is actually a class method, so you need to import the whole class and instance it in the second file

**prgm.py**

```
class Example:
   def move(self):
       H = newtest.myfunction() 
       i = H.index(z)
       user = newuser.my_function()
       return user[i]
```

**test.py**

```
from prgm import Example

example = Example()
user = example.move()
# do things with user
```